# Why does JTable only present 1st row of data?

Tags: java, database, swing, loops, jtable

I'm starting to learn how to use databases and was trying to export the data from my h2 database into a JTable. The table comes up with the correct number of rows, however, only the first row is filled with data. The rest is a blank grid. I posted some code below for the JTable. If someone needs to see more code, I'll post it.

```
public class Table extends JTable{

    public static int rows;
    public static String[][] data;
    public static String[] columns = {"Author", "Customer", "Date"};

    public static void populateTable() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

//Server is name of the database class
        Server server = new Server();

        Statement stat = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);        
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM data");
        rs.last();
        rows = rs.getRow();
        rs.beforeFirst();

        data = new String[3][rows];

        while(rs.next()){
           int i = 0;
           data[0][i] = rs.getString("Author");
           data[1][i] = rs.getString("Customer");
           data[2][i] = rs.getString("Date");
           System.out.println(rs.getString("Author"));
           i = i++;
        }
        rs.close();
    }
}

class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel{

        String[] columnNames = {"Author", "Customer", "Date"};

        MyTableModel() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
            addColumn(columnNames[0]);
            addColumn(columnNames[1]);
            addColumn(columnNames[2]);
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return rows;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
            return columnNames[columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return data[columnIndex][rowIndex];

    }
```

I'm also able to print to the console all the data, but it just won't show up in the JTable. I have been stuck on this problem for hours but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement is a no-op since `i` is assigned before it is incremented

```
i = i++;
```

just use

```
i++;
```

Also initialize `i` before entering the loop

Comment: Such a simple thing. Thank you so much

Comment: In addition your array indices appear the wrong way around - dont you want to assign the values per row - `data[i][0] = rs.getString("Author");`, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

You should either use a for loop or declare i outside of your loop. As it stands, you are setting all data to row 0 (int i = 0);

```
while(rs.next()){
           int i = 0; // this will run for every row
           data[0][i] = rs.getString("Author");
           data[1][i] = rs.getString("Customer");
           data[2][i] = rs.getString("Date");
           System.out.println(rs.getString("Author"));
           i = i++;
        }
```